# New Object getting created while using CallBack methods in Java?

Tags: java, callback

I am trying to make use of Callback functionality in Java. But I get a ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception while implementing it

**CallBackInterface.java**

```
interface CallBackInterface {

    public void onCallBack(int position);
}
```

**First.java**

```
public class First implements CallBackInterface {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new First().goGo();

    }

    public void goGo(){
        list.add("one");
        CallBackInterface obj = new First();
        Second second = new Second(obj);
        second.getPosition();
    }
    public void onCallBack(int position) {
        list.remove(0);

    }
}
```

**Second.java**

```
class Second {

    CallBackInterface callback;

    public Second(CallBackInterface callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public void getPosition() {
        callback.onCallBack(0);
    }
}
```

**Here is the stacktrace: **

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
    at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:474)
    at org.help.adapters.First.onCallBack(First.java:28)
    at org.help.adapters.Second.getPosition(First.java:43)
    at org.help.adapters.First.goGo(First.java:25)
    at org.help.adapters.First.main(First.java:17)
```

In Method onCallBack() I get an ArrayIndexOutException, which is because list is empty. So while using callbacks are the objects initialized again ?  What do I need to do to use the same list in the callback method?

Comment: What do you think `CallBackInterface obj = new First();` does? Have you added anything to this **new** `First` object?

Comment: I cannot add any methods or members of First.java to obj.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: got it..realized what I was doing wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the callback that's creating a new object, it's you.

```
CallBackInterface obj = new First();
Second second = new Second(obj);
```

Instead pass this object

```
Second second = new Second(this);
```

since `this` object already has an element added to its `List`.